# No "UnityEngine.SceneManagement" in UnityEngine namespace?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a complete beginner in Unity. I was following a YouTube video to learn.

In the video `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` was imported then the instructor changed the scene by using `SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename);`

When I did that, it showed an error. How can I fix that?
I am currently using Unity 5.0.

Mainmenu.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class mainmenu : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject levelButtonPrefab;
    public GameObject levelButtonContainer;

    private void Start(){
        Sprite[] thumbnails = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Levels");

        foreach (Sprite thumbnail in thumbnails) {
            GameObject container = Instantiate(levelButtonPrefab)as GameObject;
            container.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = thumbnail;
            container.transform.SetParent(levelButtonContainer.transform,false);
            string scene = thumbnail.name;
            container.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(()=>loadlevel(thumbnail.name));
        }
    }

    private void loadlevel(string scene){
        Debug.Log("1");
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Assets/script/mainmenu.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name SceneManagement does not exist in the namespace UnityEngine.
>   Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting and the code you have written?

Comment: updated @JamesHogle

Comment: can your post your `mainmenu` script as well?

Comment: updated that too @JamesHogle

Comment: scenemanager is also not getting displayed in autocomplete suggestions

Comment: That script compiles on my machine. Are you using the latest version of unity? If not what version are you using?

Comment: I am on 5.0 @JamesHogle

Comment: I believe SceneManagement was added after version 5.0.  I bet if you update to the latest unity version 5.4.1 the issue will be resolved.

Comment: The video tutorials I am following were made on march 2016. @JamesHogle So do u think that's an issue?

Comment: I downloaded this unity in august

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125635/discussion-between-james-hogle-and-bucky-roid).

Comment: Indeed - `SceneManager` was only added in version 5.3, as mentioned in the [release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.3).

Comment: Ohk going to update

Comment: Would it be okay if I added this as an answer? I suspect this could be a potential confusion going forward for others as well, since a lot of people are probably still using < 5.3.

Comment: I am on slow internet right now.. So It's 2am right now.. I am going put it on update and then sleep.. And yes you can answer if this is the actual solution for this problem.. But still confused because the youtube videos are 6months old

Comment: It does seem like a while ago, but the original release of Unity 5.3 was actually at the end of 2015. Hopefully the update is all it takes to solve your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` namespace was introduced in the release of Unity 5.3 (Dec. 2015), as the [relevant update notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.3) are the first to mention the deprecation of previous scene management implementations:

> Deprecated: EditorApplication class [...] and Application class [...] APIs. They all redirect to equivalent APIs on
>   EditorSceneManager or SceneManager but it is recommended to start
>   using the new APIs instead.

To make use of classes within this namespace such as `SceneManager`, you will need to update to the latest version of Unity (or at least version 5.3).

Comment: Hey When I start unity i am getting a blank screen. After searching on google for fix, i found that I have to make a folder in app data and copy unityeditor-cloud-hub-0.0.1.tgz it.. Can u tell me where can i download? :(

Comment: @BuckyĎroid Hm? Based on reading probably the [same threads](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1076312/black-screen-when-you-start-unity3d.html), that file should be in C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\Packages, right? (I guess I must have been lucky, not having to do that step when I updated.)

Comment: I dont find that file. I mean i got a link to download that file but the file had been removed.. If you have that file,then can you pleasse send ? :(

Comment: going to post this issue as an another question